# How to send request and get response from IBM MQ using JMS?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mainframe

I have sent the request to and from MQ using JMS. I have provided the program name, commarea, call length, and waiting time as inputs. However, I am encountering the following exception.

```java
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidSelectorException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SY31.MQ'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.

WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2459' ('MQRC_SELECTOR_SYNTAX_ERROR').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
```

How to resolve this exception?

```java
            producer.send(message);
            
            // Receive a message from reply queue

            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue,
                    message.getJMSCorrelationID());
            
            Message replyMessage = consumer.receive(replyTimeout * 1000);

            if (replyMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
                
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. TextMessage ");
                String replText = ((TextMessage) replyMessage).getText();
                logger.info(" Reply from CICS server.. " + replText);
                }else if (replyMessage instanceof BytesMessage) {
                BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) replyMessage;
                
int length = (int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength();
                
                
                byte[] messageBytes = new byte[length];
                
                bytesMessage.readBytes(messageBytes);
                
                String textMessage = new String(messageBytes, "UTF-8");
                    
            }

            // Close resources
            session.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in JMS Queue reading========" + e);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to JMS Session `createConsumer(Destination, String)` should be a JMS selector string. Your code is using the raw `JMSCorrelationId` from `message` which does not have the correct syntax for a message selector.

The correct syntax is described in [this IBM MQ documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=messages-message-selectors-in-jms).

The general JMS syntax for matching on a JMS correlation id of `theId` would be `JMSCorrelationId='theId'`.

IBM MQ also has special syntax for selecting by correlation id if the correlation id is an MQ CorrelId, which is a 24-byte byte string, and the selection is for an exact match. The syntax to match a message with MQ CorrelId `CorrelId` would be `JMSCorrelationId='ID:CorrelId'`. MQ will optimise this form of selector.

There are examples of this in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer from @Rich, take a look at [this sample code](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/e85a99282e3ba4d20a764b489f170e5bc1bd491f/JMS/com/ibm/mq/samples/jms/JmsRequest.java).

The requester code shows how to create a correlation id, add it to the request message, and then how to use it as a selector for the reply.

Key elements from that code for you are:

```java
            String correlationID = ...

            ...

            byte[] b = null;
            String selector = "";
            try {
                b = correlationID.getBytes();
                selector = "JMSCorrelationID='ID:" + getHexString(b) + "'";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info(e.getMessage());
            }

            ...
            

            logger.info("Selecting reply based on selector " + selector);
            JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(requestQueue, selector);
```

where

```java
    public static String getHexString(byte[] b) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```